# Exclude cloud run from outer internet

Tags: google-cloud-run, vpc, google-cloud-endpoints-v2, google-vpc

I have backend and google endpoints service (both on cloud run). Endpoints service provides information from backend for authorized users. I want to make backend not accessible from outer internet. There are possibility to allow only inner connections by setting **Ingress -> Allow internal traffic only**. If I do that my endpoints service can't reach backend. All endpoints and backend connected to the same VPC. How can I exclude backend from outer internet? [how I want it be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2VZ0t.png)

Comment: Something like this: https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/tutorials/secure-services ?

Comment: I need to resolve it using vpc

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 solutions:

1. Continue to expose your backend service to the internet but make it secures (IAM protected service, deployed with `--noallow-unauthenticated` option). However, grant only the service account of your endpoint service to reach the backend. Like that all the unauthenticated and the unauthorized traffic will be filtered by GFE (Google Front End) and discarded automatically. Only allowed traffic will reach the backend. That solution has the advantage to allow you to also test the backend in case of issue for example, with the correct permissions.
2. The second solution is exactly what you want:

- Set the backend ingress to internal only
- Create a serverless VPC connector, add it to the endpoint service with the egress control to ALL.

Like that, all the traffic of the endpoint will be routed through the VPC connector, land in your VPC and then, internally access your backend. Why egress=all?? Because, even if you set your backend ingress to internal, the Cloud Run URL is still public (but an additional check is done to be sure that the traffic comes from your VPC, it's named [authenticated network traffic](https://cloud.google.com/security/encryption-in-transit#virtual-network))

At the end, it's always authentication based (on network source or on service account identity). The serverless VPC connection costs about $17 per month

Comment: I tried to set egress=all but then endpoints service says "Jwks remote fetch is failed". I found that I can set firewall rule for my connector. So I created Egress Allow with target tag made by template vpc-connector-REGION-CONNECTOR_NAME for 0.0.0.0/0 and all protocol and ports. I tried to set different priority 999, 1000, 1001 but still had "Jwks remote fetch is failed". At the same time in a firewall rules log these connections marked as allowed

Comment: What's your code? What's use Jwks?

Comment: Jwks is used by endpoints service to check user's JWT. I have no code for this. It's https://cloud.google.com/endpoints. Everything works fine without VPC

Comment: Can you check if you have the private google access set on the subnet of your VPC connector?

Comment: It's Off. Should be on?

Comment: I don't know, but it could solve the issue. Have a try!

Comment: It didn't. And it would be strange if does. Endpoinds service making request to third-party service for jwks

Comment: Oh, ok, it's an external jwt validation right?

Comment: Yes. It is. But requests can't go outside VPC even when I created firewall rule